# How to allow variables to be used in a csh script called from another csh script?

Tags: csh

I have a script `caller.csh` in which I call another one `called.sh`. I declare some variables using `set` command in `caller.csh` (e.g. `set alpha = 10`). How do I use them in `called.sh` (e.g. `echo $alpha`) without passing them as command line parameters?

Note that the script `called.sh` can be run standalone and the variables are defined in it also. I would like these variable values to be overridden by those in `caller.sh`. So I'll use something like `if not defined $alpha, then set alpha =` in `called.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set them as environment variables (using `setenv`).

However, this is not a good approach.  The interface for passing variables to a shell script should be via the command-line options/arguments.  If it's a shell script, it should be standalone-ish.  How else would you pass the same arguments when running it directly from command line?

EDIT: following the update to the second part of your question.  Use `getopt`.  You can set the variables your default values, and then use `getopt` to override those values in case the user passes them as command-line options/arguments.  This approach is preferable to any kind of globally-defined variables.

Comment: Thanks. Can there be something like global variables in `C`? Please also see a note I added to the question (2nd para)